# Insert Jquery file at the bottom of body or head tag

Tags: php, curl, preg-replace

I'm using CURL to scrape some website and I would like to insert Jquery file so I did:

```
$curl_scraped_page = preg_replace("/<*>/i", "<head><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' />", $curl_scraped_page, 1);
```

This seems to work, the script is added to the page which is being extracted and echoed. The problem is that some websites don't function properly anymore. I think because the Jquery script is causing a conflict with other scripts in the page. I think it would help if I put the Jquery at the bottom of head or body tag instead of the top. How do I do this? Al I can think of is:

```
$curl_scraped_page = preg_replace("/<*>/i", "</head><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' />", $curl_scraped_page, 1);
```

But this has same effect as previous code.

Comment: what if that site's already using jquery and you're just trying to double-load it?

Comment: @Marc That wouldn't derail the website, I assume the last jquery file in dom tree will simply override the first one

Comment: These are some of the websites: http://www.ns.nl/ and http://www.telegraaf.nl/

Comment: yes, but replacing (say) jquery v0.9 with 1.9 is definitely going to break things. there's been some major internal rewrites in jquery over the years, and they're not backwards compatible.

Comment: @Marc B I see your point...thanks. Any suggestions on that?